Magic Enhancement Critique
Spoiler Warning: This question contains references to the Stormlight archive mechanics. I love it and I would hate anyone being spoiled so please be warned.
Warning: Long text ahead
I have this campaign that we've been running for a while where the heroes are captured and experimented on by a quasi divine being, a guardian as they come to known him; they manage to escape and have multiple adventures. As part of the campaign the heroes are imprinted with a tatoo on their forearms which, initially, they can use instinctively to create a magic barrier or to invoke haste on themselves without spending an action once per long rest.
10 levels after they have reached a point in the campaign where I'm ready to unlock the next element of the magic system. This is a major shift on dynamics on Pathfinder which will, undoubtfully, break the encounter balance and I will have to compensate for it. I'm ready for that. My plan is to base it on the stormlight radiants abilities.
The general rules go as follows:
First Heightening
Yes, this is taken directly from warbreaker system.

Ability to cast Magic Barrier as a reaction. It reduces 20 points of damage from a single attack source.
Ability to cast Haste on yourself without spending an action.

Recover on every rest. This is what they already had.
This provided a nice boost for the characters on the initial levels, effectively giving a heoric turn occasionally. As they grow into higher levels it became less and less powerful.
Second Heightening
Soul Essence
In this point I need an economy system to tie to the powers so I introduced soul essence. This has already been foreshadowed in the campaign as the guardian killed a baby to gather soul essence to expand and fuel his powers. It's also meant to introduce a ethic dylema, they can ALWAYS get soul essence, as long as they are willing to kill for it.
Other than killing, the plan is to allow them to collect soul essence mineral on certain points, it can't be bought but, by having a certain mineral, they can store soul essence for later use. Every kill of a natural intelligent creature (not demons or constructs or animals) can be trapped by succeding on natural roll against a difficulty of 9 + the number of turns since the creature was killed. This takes three actions to achieve. Once stored it lasts for a month and then disipates.
The "power" of the soul depends on the remaining years of life (potential) with exponential decay. A newborn (under 6 months) provides 20 soul essences, a baby (under a year) provides 10 soul essences, a child (1 to 10 years) provide 3 soul essences, a youngster up to 19 years provides 2 soul essences, 20 to 60 provides 1 and over that age you get a 50% chance of getting something (this obviously translates to the life expectancy of the creature)
The heroes also have the ability to "suck" the soul essence from the creatures that die in battle directly with a 50% chance of success and the same quantity as above.
I don't think they will as they all have children, but if they go nuts I'm happy to explore turning them into baby killing machines and turning the world against them (this path has also been foreshadowed in the campaing)
Powers of the second heightening

Healing:

You can heal yourself up to 10 points per soul essence spent as a reaction.
You can spend as many as you want. You can do this even if unconcious.


Enhanced Movemement.

You gain +1 to AC per soul essence spent.
Lasts for 2 rounds.


Increase Attack Precision.

You gain +1 to attack rolls per soul essence spent.
Last for 2 rounds.


Damage Boost.

You gain +5 damage per soul essence spent (double on critical).
Applies to a single attack


Action Surge.

You gain 1 action per every 2 soul essence spent
Instantaneous and does not require a action to cast.


Enhanced Magic Barrier

You deflect 50% of the damage of an attack by spending 3 soul essences
You deflect 75% of the damage of an attack by spending 5 soul essences



Consequences
Every usage of soulcasting risks damaging the veil and enabling demons to reach our worlds. This doesn't happen often but it's a real posibility. Every time the ability is use there's a chance the veil breaks letting a creature from beyond reach our world (DMs choice). Every time the ability is used you roll a D20, if you get a value higher than 20 - soul essence spent, the veil breaks and a creature crosses over. Healing is the only ability that does not trigger this effect
This is intended to introduce random risk to using the abilities.
Implications of the Second Heightening
Now, this implies a number of things. All characters are able to spend points to increase their chances of hit, their damage, they can heal and protect themselves and they can act several times.
Spellcasters will be able to cast more than one spell per round, potentially causing devastating combos, physical characters get a more direct benefit.
Third Heightening
I'm still working on this but this will come later and it will add specific abilities related to each class (different for wizards, warriors, etc)
The questions
First of, if you've read this much, thanks a lot.
My doubts comes from the balancing act. This is meant to provide a power increase that is balanced across all different classes. I have, specifically, a party composed by a Fighter, a Rogue, a Druid and a Wizard. I want to make sure the Second Heightening provides a comparable power increase to all of them and doesn't leave anyone feeling their character got less out of the deal. Specially since this is a very powerful bonus and it is likely to break many things.
In general soul essence is expected to be very limited. I usually expect players to be able to gather between 5 and 10 soul essences total per long rest, usually to distribute among the four players.
I'm looking for pointers or critics to be able to adjust for equality across players. I know this will need to be balanced on encounters and that we will playtest as  I can cheat a bit and adjust on the go.

You may want to refer to the new Mythic rules found in the new War of Immortals sourcebook, due out in a few weeks. (Subscribers already have their PDF's). It is a pretty good drop-in solution that appears to be usable for everything you're trying to do here, if you just hand out the appropriate specific mythic feats.

Consider These as Deviant Abilities
Deviant abilities are an optional rule for Pathfinder 2e which govern abilities similar to what you've described here, as substantial powers beyond a typical character's that expand with experience and have a chance for consequences with each use. These abilities are granted by deviant feats, and for an idea like this it'd probably make sense to grant them as background deviant abilities that don't take up a character's usual class feats:

When using background deviant abilities, the player should get to decide what type of deviation they want and build their power. As the player grows, they should be able to improve their deviant ability, whether through special training, seeking out objects of power, or self-improvement, represented as taking additional deviant ability feats. If everyone in your party wishes to make deviant abilities a part of their character, or for a setting where these abilities are more common, consider using a variant similar to the free archetype variant rule to grant each character an extra class feat at 2nd level and every even-numbered level thereafter that they can use only to take deviant feats. In most cases, they can gain every possible deviant ability feat by 16th level in this fashion, so there's no need to grant extra feats after that.

It might be good to allow your players to come up with some of the effects of their deviant abilities, or otherwise you could write these up as falling into a few different deviant classifications so each character could have their own customized abilities as you mentioned. The examples given in the Dark Archive where these rules released are a bit more limited than what you've written up here, but there were some new classifications Verdant Core and Blight Soul in a recent adventure but aren't up on Archives of Nethys yet:

 Wardens of Wildwood: Severed at the Root

In particular it might be good to base the healing power off of the Verdant Core's 1-action ability to Sprout Fruit:

The plants covering your body sprout a single, ripe fruit.
A creature other than you who eats this fruit as a three-
action activity (1 Interact action to pluck the fruit and 2
Interact actions to eat it) is healed 1d4 Hit Points for every
2 levels you have.
Awakening The fruit is more potent. Increase the healing
from d4s to d6s.
Awakening The fruit is plentiful. You sprout one
additional fruit for every 5 levels you have beyond 2. Also,
those who eat a fruit may reduce a condition affecting
them by 1.

Compared to your current proposal the main change would be that backlash is more common but scaling in danger, where some moderate penalty might be applied at first before ramping up with each consecutive failure in a day. This could culminate as severe backlash in your current proposal for consequences where some creature invades their reality.

How do deviant abilities impact balance? Do you have experience, how often these are used by characters? Where on the scale are deviant abilities compared to class feats/spells (leveled/cantrip) or item effects?

@Kekse Many of the official options are powerful beyond equivalent spells, but have substantial risk. In spite of the risk they've usually been used by my party around 3+ times a day, varying wildly on the number of encounters and danger.
